# How do I lowercase the first letter of part of my urls address?

Tags: python, html, django

I created a for-loop in the template.html to have several buttons direct to different URLs with the product names specified:

```
<a href=http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/{{product.name}} class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</a>
```

For example, if you click the button for pizza, you will be directed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/Pizza
However, the product names I assigned are all capitalized; how I can address the URLs to be http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/pizza instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/Pizza?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template use [lower](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#lower)  function like this :

```
<a href=http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/{{product.name|lower}} class="btn btn-primary">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Welcome, if this answer helps you then you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark.